# The unknown country

Tags: riddle, knowledge

**Which country and person am I thinking of?**

"And here I am, sitting on a rock in the mountains, just us 3, looking at the stars, the sky so clear. The Sugarcanes are visible from here.
"Do you think they will find us?" I stutter with fear.
We have nothing as defense, but at least the damage won't be too immense.
The plan failed but still we won at the very end.
And I may not forget Russia is still my friend."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think with the mention of `The Sugarcanes` and the reference to Russia as a friend, the country mentioned in the passage should be

> Cuba. Sugar is its principal agricultural economy and historically, Russia has had friendly relations with Cuba. And I believe the person should be Fidel Castro.

Comment: And who do you think is the person i am thinking of?

Comment: @Kathi I added the person to the answer, since apparently there is no spoiler tag in the comments.

Comment: Good job, that's both correct, I know that wasn't easy, therefore congrats

Answer (score 2):

We have multiple hints in the text which lead to Fidel castro and cuba

1. in the mountains, just us 3 - Castro fled with Che Guevara and his brother into the Sierra maestro mountains
2. stars symbolized castro
3. will they find us - cubas president looked for castro when a coup failed
4. we have nothing as defense - Castro didn't have any weapons after they fled
5. the plan failed should be clear by now
6. won at the very end, Castro was president of Cuba and I think the son of his brother is president right now
7. as mentioned in the answer Russia supported Cuba against the US